# Get symbolic form of constraint

Tags: drake

For an arbitrary constraint, how do I get a symbolic form?

I.e. given a constraint object, I want to know that the quadratic is x^T Q x <= b or Ax <= b. I don't have ability to name the constraint, e.g. when using any various Drake built-in functions such as the MISO3 constraint.

I want the symbolic form, but also the actual values, i.e. x^T Q x and also want to know what Q is.

Answer (score 2):

Use the symbolic Eval function to get an Expression for the output of the constraint:

```py
import numpy as np
from pydrake.all import *
prog = MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(3)
foo = prog.AddQuadraticConstraint(Q=np.eye(2), b=np.array([1., 2.]), lb=-1, ub=1, vars=x[:2])
expr = foo.evaluator().Eval(foo.variables())
print(expr)
```

prints

```
[<Expression "(x(0) + 2 * x(1) + 0.5 * pow(x(0), 2) + 0.5 * pow(x(1), 2))">]
```

If you need direct access to the constituent Q and b matrices, you'll need to re-factor them yourself from the expression.

Alternatively, you can use `isinstance(foo.evaluator(), QuadraticConstraint)` to check for specific types and then call `foo.Q()` or `foo.A()` directly once you know the type.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to write the same.  All of those queries are easy with the constraint API:

```
import numpy as np
from pydrake.solvers import QuadraticConstraint
from pydrake.symbolic import Variable

Q = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 2]])
b = [3, 4]
lb = -5
ub = 6

c = QuadraticConstraint(Q, b, lb, ub)

x = [7, 8]
print(c.Eval(x))
x = [Variable("x1"), Variable("x2")]
print(c.Eval(x))
print(c.Q())
print(c.b())
print(c.lower_bound())
print(c.upper_bound())
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of constraint you query. Some constraints have implemented `Eval()` function for symbolic variables (for example a LinearConstraint). Some constraints don't (for example MinimumDistanceConstraint).

Here is a quick example on printing the symbolic quadratic constraint.

```py
prog = MathematicalProgram();
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2, "x")
constraint = prog.AddQuadraticConstraint(x(0) * x(0) - 2 * x(1)*x(1), 1, 2)

# Now evaluate this constraint in the symbolic form for x.
constraint_eval = constraint.evaluator().Eval(x)
print(constraint_eval)
# Now print the Q matrix
print(f"Q={constraint.evaluator().Q()}");
```

On my computer it prints symbolic expression.

```
[<Expression "(pow(x(0), 2) - 2 * pow(x(1), 2))">]
Q = [[2. 0],
[0, -4]]
```

Notice that Drake's QuadraticConstraint stores `0.5 * x' * Q * x + b' * x` with a factor 0.5 for its quadratic term.